# firebase applyActionCode always returns "auth/invalid-action-code"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

Firebase returns invalid-action-code, when verifying an email.
Things to note: i made my own email logic/template; ie I manually generate the codes on firebase functions and dispatch them in the sent email.

**The issue is, even though it returns "invalid-action-code", the user gets verified correctly**. So it's a false positive. However I cannot differentiate from real-invalid-code cases.

```
    const auth = getAuth();
    let error = false;
    await applyActionCode(auth, actionCode)
        .catch(err => {
            error = {
                code: err.code,
                message: err.message
            }
        })
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. It used to work a couple of weeks ago and it is not working now.

Comment: In my case, the issue was that useEffect was getting called twice.